# Is there a way to run JavaScript on a page I can't access?

Tags: javascript

I have a client who wants me to send him a script to put on his site. Is there a way to inject the script into the page on my browser for testing purposes to make sure it works?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about using an iframe?

Comment: If the site is static you could always copy/paste the source into your IDE and mess with your JS there.

Comment: what about pasting into developer console?

Comment: tampermonkey works for chrome, bookmarklets work everywhere, just use them to inject your external script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use my browser's developer tools (such as [Chrome's really nice ones](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)) to add a new `<script>` tag to the `<head>`.

For example, if you want to add jQuery to the page (which I've done from time to time on sites that don't already have it), you could open up your developer tools (`Cmd+Shift+I` does it for me on Mac in both Chrome and Firefox, `F12` works in IE), go to the JS console (usually just labeled "Console"), and enter the following:

```
var newScript = document.createElement( 'script' );
newScript.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
var head = document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ];
head.appendChild( newScript );
```

At that point, you've added a new `<script>` to the page (*for this page load only*), and it will load and execute as any other would.

If you wanted to get really fancy with it, you could make sure to run it in a certain place on the page (say, after a given script has loaded but before the next one) with some use of the debugger (also in your developer tools), but that's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can use some plugins/extensions for the browser that you use to help you. You can use greesemonkeys for firefox, for example. You can find more for chrome and other browsers.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Most current browsers ship with a web inspector / console built in.